# Calling PATCH API method returns 400 error?

Tags: http, abap, patch

I'm trying to call a PATCH Method API within ABAP, but i am always getting code 400 back with error message that content type is not supported, its needed application/json which i am setting already in the code.

```
    cl_http_client=>create_by_url(
      EXPORTING
        url                = lv_url
      IMPORTING
        client             = lo_client
      EXCEPTIONS
        argument_not_found = 1
        plugin_not_active  = 2
        internal_error     = 3
        OTHERS             = 4 ).
  
*   Set request parameter (Authorization)
    lo_client->request->set_header_field(
      name  = mc_param_name_authorization
      value = mc_auth_type_bearer && | { mv_access_token }|
    ).


*   Set request parameter (apiKey)
    lo_client->request->set_header_field(
      name  = mc_param_name_apikey
      value = CONV string( ms_access_settings-api_key )
    ).


*   Set request parameter (realm)
    lo_client->request->set_header_field(
      name  = mc_param_name_realm
      value = get_realm( mc_api_call_approve )
    ).
    lo_client->request->set_method( 'PATCH' ).
    lo_client->request->set_content_type( 'application/json' ).
    lo_http_client->request->set_cdata( lv_body_json ).

    lo_client->send( ).

    lo_client->receive(
      EXCEPTIONS
        http_communication_failure = 1
        http_invalid_state         = 2
        http_processing_failed     = 3
        OTHERS                     = 4 ).
```

Comment: If you get the code 400, it means that the server delivers it to you. It has probably nothing to do with ABAP. Moreover without the access to the remote resource (the one under `lv_url`) it is almost impossible to help you.

Comment: 400 = Bad Request -> please show the whole HTTP request (and whole HTTP response).

Comment: As Sandra said, the full body might indicate why it was declined. Common reasons that it works in e.g. postman but not ABAP/code are missing headers like `User-Agent`. If it works in postman, try to add all the headers it displays there